# How to dynamically load templateUrl depends on the value

Tags: angular

I'm building a page component for a different type of page and I want to dynamically load templateUrl depends on what type of page.

**page.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-page',
  templateUrl: './type_of_page.component.html', // <-- i want this to dynamically load
  styleUrls: ['./page.component.scss']
})
export class PageComponent implements OnInit {

  type_of_page = 'person'; // person

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
    this.http.get('api/type-of-page?id=1').subscribe(response => {
      this.type_of_page = response['type_of_page']; // tv series
    });
  }

}
```

Is there a way to achieve this **only** inside the page.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use ng-template tag in your container component, that solves your problem of loading template / component dynamically.

```
https://stackblitz.com/angular/ndjkdnmaqdn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fad-banner.component.ts
```

Comment: @paulws please follow above mentioned link. That has working example of loading dynamic template / component.

Comment: I want to do everything only inside the page.component.ts

Comment: Yeah, you can do that, since page.component.ts is your Smart / Container Component. 
In the example 'AdBannerComponent' is the Smart component so, logic resides in that component.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a way that works better with Angular ecosystem, and it's a popular way that more people are using it. You can load the `page.component.html` itself, and inside that component, decide what page you want to load and use `ngIf` to use your desired component.

**page.component.html**

```
<app-page1 *ngIf="showPage1"></app-page1>
<app-page2 *ngIf="!showPage1"></app-page2> <!-- !showPage1 means not show page1-->
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this one already but I have about 30+ types of page that I want to dynamically load